# Fourier transform with displacement on time

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm attempting to calculate the Fourier Transform of the following function
$$
g(t)=\Bigg\{ \begin{array}{ll}
      \pi, \ |t-3|<1
      \\
      0, \ |t-3|>1
      \end{array} 
$$
My approach is using the definition of the Fourier Transform $\mathcal F (\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) e^{-i\omega t} \ dt$ as
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{2}^{4}\pi e^{-i \omega t}dt = \frac{i}{2 \omega}\left( e^{-i \omega 4} - e^{-i \omega 2}\right)= e^{-3i \omega}\frac{sin(\omega)}{\omega}
$$
Observe that I've ommited the integrals where the value of the function is $0$.

I'm seriously doubting of the validity of what I have done and the fact that Wolfram returns a slightly different answer makes me doubt even more. Thank you.

Comment: The form of the result is correct. The Fourier transform of the indicator function $1_{[-1, 1]}$ is $\frac{\sin\omega}{\omega}$ and the translate gives the factor $e^{-3i\omega}.$ If something is incorrect in your answer, it's "only" factors.

Comment: Appreciate it man!

Comment: It looks like there should be a minus sign in front.

Comment: In front of the answer or where do you mean?